# Usercontrol in windows Form closed when my BackgroundWorker is running

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

I made a form with 3 usercontrols and display it with button.
In 2 of them I got a form for make a backup SQL and a restore.
For the backup my usercontrol get closed after the back is complete.
For the restore I run a background Worker and my usercontrol get closed in the middle of the process.

There is no error so I don't know what to do.

I try nothing because i have no error

I add my user-control in my form with this

```cs
if (!Instance.PanelContainer.Controls.ContainsKey("Backup"))
{
    Backup backup = new Backup();
    backup.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    PanelTools.Controls.Add(backup);
}
Instance.PanelContainer.Controls["Backup"].BringToFront();
```

Then I just have a button that run a SQL Query

```sql
BACKUP DATABASE DBPDM
TO DISK = 'PathBackupNameBackup'
WITH
  FORMAT,
  MEDIANAME = 'SQLServerBackups',
  NAME = 'Full Backup of SQLTestDB';
```

And the crash is at the end of BAK

UPDATE :

I find the issue with the restore UserControl. It's because I kill explorer.exe.

Usercontrol is an explorer.exe ? Can I kill explorer without that close my usercontrol ?

Comment: There's not much to go on here. A [mcve] would be useful.

Comment: I add my user-control in my form with this

if (!Instance.PanelContainer.Controls.ContainsKey("Backup"))
            {
                Backup backup = new Backup();
                backup.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
                PanelTools.Controls.Add(backup);
            }
            Instance.PanelContainer.Controls["Backup"].BringToFront();

Then I just have a button that run a SQL Query 

BACKUP DATABASE DBPDM
TO DISK = 'PathBackupNameBackup'
   WITH FORMAT,
      MEDIANAME = 'SQLServerBackups',
      NAME = 'Full Backup of SQLTestDB';

And the crash is at the end of BAK

Comment: Sorry it's my first questions on this site I'm not good already for poste my code and explaination + i'm a noob in developpement and my english is not perfect ^^

Thanks for your answer btw !!!

Comment: Please don't add relevant information in comments, you can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71764509/edit) your question and add all relevant and usefull information there.

Comment: Where is the code that starts the `BackgroundWorker` where is the code that closes the form? How do you know there is no exception, perhaps you have an unhandled error on the background thread which is shutting the application? Try running it in the debugger

Comment: Sorry, I never close the User-control with a code. It's close by itself.
Maybe we can forget BackgroundWorker and just focus on Backup?

Comment: Can I join a video on this site?

Comment: *"I find the issue with the restore UserControl. It's because I kill explorer.exe. Usercontrol is an explorer.exe ? Can I kill explorer without that close my usercontrol ?"* makes no sense. What has a `UserControl` which is a WinFroms control, got to do with `explorer.exe` which is an application? And why are you killing it?

Comment: I dont know.. I kill explorer.exe because I got Solidworks PDM (it use explorer) and I restore a DB (I can’t restore if it’s used)

Comment: But when I comment my code for kill explorer.exe my Usercontrol doesn’t get closed anymore…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update of my issue.
My Usercontrol doesn't get close but like I said I've got 3 usercontrol.
When my app is starting I load the usercontrol 1.
With a button I load a usercontrol 2.

When the explorer.exe get kill the usercontrol 1 is bringback to front.
I see it's because I load this one on a PaintEvent like that :

```
private void PanelTools_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        _obj = this;
        if (!Instance.PanelContainer.Controls.ContainsKey("Settings"))
        {
            Settings settings = new Settings();
            settings.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            PanelTools.Controls.Add(settings);
        }
        Instance.PanelContainer.Controls["Settings"].BringToFront();
    }
```

to fix it I just load my usercontrol 1 on the LoadEvent :

```
 private void SupportTools_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _obj = this;
        if (!Instance.PanelContainer.Controls.ContainsKey("Settings"))
        {
            Settings settings = new Settings();
            settings.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            PanelTools.Controls.Add(settings);
        }
        Instance.PanelContainer.Controls["Settings"].BringToFront();
    }
```

Thanks a lot for your time all and sorry for not being clear when i explain my issue.